# How do I add class to body when div height is smaller than window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm trying to add a class to the body if a certain divs height is smaller than the users window size. Here is my current jQuery script. It doesn't work very well, and I don't get any errors. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $pageHeight = $('.wrap').height();
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.height();
        if (windowsize < $pageHeight) {
            $('body').addClass('need-padding');
        }
    }
    checkWidth();   
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: as far as i can see you are adding the class 'need-padding' when window size is  lesser than div with class 'wrap' --->  [Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/gvgk3y6h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... no need to create separate function :

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
     var $windowHeight = $(window).height();
     var $blockHeight = $('.wrap').height();
        if ($blockHeight < $windowHeight ) {
            //console.log($windowHeight+" Window Height");
            //console.log($blockHeight+" Block Height");
            $('body').addClass('need-padding');
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the code looks ok. But if your `$('.wrap')` has margins or borders, you might want to use use `.outerHeight()` instead of `.height()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that shows what's going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/4fqb8t1q/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth();   
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});  
function checkWidth() {
    var $pageHeight = $('.wrap').height();
    alert($(window).height() + " < " + $pageHeight);
    if ($(window).height() < $pageHeight) {
        $('body').addClass('need-padding');
    }
}
```